# how to retrieve php result in every 1 sec using ajax & jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
var manageMemberTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval( function () {
manageMemberTable = $("#manageMemberTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": "php_action/retrieve.php",
    "order": []
    });

manageMemberTable.ajax.load('php_action/retrieve.php')
}, 100);
```

[image]

Hello, I want to reload this datatable in every 1 second... please help

Comment: You should get menageMemberTable out of your interval and use setTimeout (or setInterval) on your ajax call.

Comment: Use 1000ms (1 second) instead 100.

Comment: @zenko OP wan't result update in every one secons, why you ask him to remove `interval` and add `settiomeout`?

Comment: Tried using SetTimeout but not working.... i guess i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @SuperUser : Got wrong on my first comment. Sry. But the answer below by Vinod is what I explained. Does it work ?

Comment: Nope ... 

$(document).ready(function() {
 manageMemberTable = $("#manageMemberTable").DataTable({
  "ajax": "php_action/retrieve.php",
  "order": []
  });

 setInterval(function () {
    manageMemberTable.ajax.reload();
 }, 1000 );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataTable's Ajax Reload.

[Datatable Ajax Reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Sample code to load the table every second is:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: "your url"
});

setInterval(function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 1000 );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there any console error or alert box? You might need to specify the request type as POST.

Comment: No there is no any error on the page....

i have made below changes as per your code

$(document).ready(function() {
 manageMemberTable = $("#manageMemberTable").DataTable({
  "ajax": "php_action/retrieve.php",
  "order": []
  });

 setInterval(function () {
    manageMemberTable.ajax.reload();
 }, 1000 );

Comment: I have created a fiddle for you which will give datatable error on each second. Refer http://jsfiddle.net/vinniechandak/3grbqo4d/

Comment: I would recommend to refer https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html for the official documentation and examples. Alan has also posted many answers regarding datatable on his blog and FAQ section. May the luck be with you!

Comment: Hey Vinod. now i just restart my laptop and rechecked your code,,, it is working... Thank You !!